# Geotransform problem when converting MODL2 hdf to tiff using pyhdf

Tags: python, coordinate-system, modis

I am to using Python to process MODIS data，and now I am trying to covert MODISL2 hdf data(atmosphere corrected products using MOD02 and Seadas) to Geotiff files for futher band calculation.
I could not obtain geotransform parameters from MODISL2 hdf matadata, so I tried using geotransform parameters extract from a projected tif file(coverted by Seadas using same MODISL2 hdf), it was fine until I got a projection problem(Incorrect coordinate values). My codes are as follows:

```
import gdal
import numpy as np
from numpy import shape
from pyhdf.SD import *
from osgeo import osr


in_tiff_path = r'D:\PythonTest\TSS calculation'
hdf_obj = SD('MODIS_2008097_SWIR.hdf')

# get attributes, layers, and single layer of Rrs
attr = hdf_obj.attributes()
dateset = hdf_obj.datasets()

columns = int(attr['Number of Pixel Control Points'])
rows = int(attr['Number of Scan Control Points'])

Rrs = hdf_obj.select('Rrs_1240').get()  
d_Rrs = Rrs.astype(np.float32)

# convert negative values of hdf  to real pixel value array
real_Rrs = (d_Rrs + 25000) / 500000
real_Rrs[real_Rrs < 0] = 0

# L2_flag
l2 = hdf_obj.select('l2_flags').get()
d_l2 = l2.astype(np.int32)

# get geotransform from tiff file converted by seadas
inpath = r'D:\PythonTest\TSS calculation\MODIS_2008097_SWIR.tif'
dataset = gdal.Open(inpath)

# creat Geotif file, set geotransform and projection
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
out_tiff = driver.Create("MODIS_2008097.tif", columns, rows, 2, gdal.GDT_Float32)

out_tiff.SetGeoTransform(dataset.GetGeoTransform())
out_tiff.SetProjection('GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG",''"7030"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,'
'AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG",''"4326"]]')

# get bands
out_tiff.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(real_Rrs)
out_tiff.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(d_l2)

out_tiff.FlushCache()
```

```
Unfortunately, I got a result with failed projection.
```

[image: Failed Projection]
Then I tried to calculate  geotransform parameters manually using  the image four corner coordinates from the HDF metadata and least squares method, then used this parameter to projection. Codes for calculation of geotransform:

```
# Calculation of affine parameter(Geo transformation)
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

def affine_abc(pixel_points, geo_points):
    n = len(pixel_points)
    pixelX_square = 0.0
    pixelX_pixelY = 0.0
    pixelY_square = 0.0
    pixelX = 0.0
    pixelY = 0.0
    pixelX_geoX = 0.0
    pixelY_geoX = 0.0
    geoX = 0.0
    for i in range(0, n):
        pixelX_square += math.pow(pixel_points[i].x, 2)
        pixelX_pixelY += pixel_points[i].x * pixel_points[i].y
        pixelY_square += math.pow(pixel_points[i].y, 2)
        pixelX += pixel_points[i].x
        pixelY += pixel_points[i].y
        pixelX_geoX += pixel_points[i].x * geo_points[i].x
        pixelY_geoX += pixel_points[i].y * geo_points[i].x
        geoX += geo_points[i].x
    a = np.array([[pixelX_square, pixelX_pixelY, pixelX], [pixelX_pixelY, pixelY_square, pixelY], [pixelX, pixelY, n]])
    b = np.array([[pixelX_geoX], [pixelY_geoX], [geoX]])
    at = np.linalg.inv(a)
    result = at.dot(b)
    return result[0, 0], result[1, 0], result[2, 0]


def affine_def(pixel_points, geo_points):
    n = len(pixel_points)
    pixelX_square = 0.0
    pixelX_pixelY = 0.0
    pixelY_square = 0.0
    pixelX = 0.0
    pixelY = 0.0
    pixelX_geoY = 0.0
    pixelY_geoY = 0.0
    geoY = 0.0
    for i in range(0, n):
        pixelX_square += math.pow(pixel_points[i].x, 2)
        pixelX_pixelY += pixel_points[i].x * pixel_points[i].y
        pixelY_square += math.pow(pixel_points[i].y, 2)
        pixelX += pixel_points[i].x
        pixelY += pixel_points[i].y
        pixelX_geoY += pixel_points[i].x * geo_points[i].y
        pixelY_geoY += pixel_points[i].y * geo_points[i].y
        geoY += geo_points[i].y
    a = np.array([[pixelX_square, pixelX_pixelY, pixelX], [pixelX_pixelY, pixelY_square, pixelY], [pixelX, pixelY, n]])
    b = np.array([[pixelX_geoY], [pixelY_geoY], [geoY]])
    at = np.linalg.inv(a)
    result = at.dot(b)
    return result[0, 0], result[1, 0], result[2, 0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p0 = Point(0.0, 0.0)
    p1 = Point(1353, 0.0)
    p2 = Point(0.0, 2029)
    p3 = Point(1353.0, 2029.0)
    g0 = Point(attr['Upper Left Longitude'], attr['Upper Left Latitude'])
    g1 = Point(attr['Upper Right Longitude'], attr['Upper Right Latitude'])
    g2 = Point(attr['Lower Left Longitude'], attr['Lower Left Latitude'])
    g3 = Point(attr['Lower Right Longitude'], attr['Lower Right Latitude'])
    ps = [p0, p1, p2, p3]
    gs = [g0, g1, g2, g3]
    abc = affine_abc(ps, gs)
    def0 = affine_def(ps, gs)
    # Geo transformation
    affine_MODIS = (abc[2], abc[0], abc[1], def0[2], def0[0], def0[1])
```

[image: Failed Projection2]
The resulting image looks better this time, but upon closer inspection I fuond  that the coordinates are still incorrect.(Failed Projection2.jpg)

Can you provide some advice or hints (for example on how to calculate the MODIS geotransform parameters correctly, etc.)?